# Why is `jq` trying to `add` to an object in a variable assignment?

Tags: sh, jq

Given the following [jq](/questions/tagged/jq) pipeline of expressions:

```
echo '{"foo": 1}' | jq '.foo + 2 as $bar | {$bar}'
```

I would expect the output:

```
{
  "bar": 3
}
```

What I get is:

```
jq: error (at <stdin>:1): number (1) and object ({"bar":2}) cannot be added
```

What is this object and why is `jq` trying to `add` to it?

I can resolve this issue with parentheses but I'm still unclear as to what was happening in the original statement:

```
echo '{"foo": 1}' | jq '(.foo + 2) as $bar | {$bar}' 
{
  "bar": 3
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your first filter was executed as if it had been parenthesized like this

```bash
echo '{"foo": 1}' | jq '.foo + (2 as $bar | {$bar})'
```

Thus, jq tried to add a number (here `1`) to an object (here `{"bar":2}`).

This is because the syntax for a variable binding, as noted in the manual's [corresponding section](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Variable%2FSymbolicBindingOperator%3A...as%24identifier%7C...), takes on the form `... as $identifier | ...`.  It "includes" the pipe and the following expression. This is reflected by the fact that a binding without the following pipe and expression cannot stand alone.

Comment: This was confusing to me too as a new jq user. Rephrasing the answer in case it is helpful to anyone else: jq's order of operations binds variables before it adds operands, so the parentheses are required to evaluate the addition before evaluating the variable binding.